# Why do I get a bitmap font on one computer but a vector font on another for the same document?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf

I am generating a pdf using `pdflatex` from the same latex file on three different computers. The pdf is generated without any warnings on all three computers and it looks almost identical. The one difference is that on my work computer, vector fonts are used while on the other two computers, the pdf has bitmap fonts.

All three machines are running a 13.04 Kubuntu and I'm using the latex packages from the distribution. On all three I simply use the default setting of `Kile` to generate the pdf.

Clearly there must be some difference in how latex is setup on these machines. It's possible that I installed some additional packages on my work computer, but I am not sure where to look.

So my question is, why does the same source result in two different PDFs? How do I make the other two computers also use vector fonts, and avoid the bitmap fonts, **without** modifying the latex source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should install the cm-super fonts.