# low resolution in text mode

Tags: text-mode

Why have I lower resolution in text mode than in math mode? Is it normal or some packages are missing?

[image]

Comment: Possibly the `cm-super` package has to be installed, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138803/ or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I added lmodern package and it works.[image]